# java - can I make an object of an object's inner class?

Tags: java

Am I allowed to do something like this in java?

```
class Class1 {

    static class Class2 {

    }
}

Class1 obj1 = new Class1();

Class1.Class2 obj2 = new obj1.getClass().Class2();
```

Comment: What does your Java compiler tell you?

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a compiler...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do it like this - if you need to use `getClass()`, you have to do the whole reflection route.

If the class is known at compile time, you can do this:

```
Class1.Class2 obj2 = new Class1.Class2();
```

If the class is not known at compile time, you do this:

```
Class inner = null;
for (Class c : obj1.getClass().getDeclaredClasses()) {
    if ("myPackage.Class1.Class2".equals(c.getName())) {
        inner = c;
        break;
    }
}
Object obj2 = inner.newInstance();
```

Comment: If you already need to know the fully qualified class name `"myPackage.Class1.Class2"`, then you may as well just use `Class1.Class2.class`. "Having a particular member class" is not part of the interface of a class in Java, but if your method only works with classes that have a member class named 'Class2' then your approach can work, if you compare with `c.getSimpleName()` instead of `c.getName()`.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt The string that I used as a string literal here could potentially come from a configuration file. I agree that if you know the full name of the class, you might as well use a static reference to it (`Class1.Class2.class`), or simply use `new Class1.Class2()`.

Answer (score 1):

In java you are allowed to create object of inner classes. You can do the following:

```
Class1.Class2 obj2 = new Class1.Class2();
```

If you need more info follow the link:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html

Answer (score 0):

Class2 is not an inner class it is a nested static class, for those you dont need an instance of outer class simply do it this way

```
import xxx.Class1.Class2;

...

Class2 obj2 = new Class2();
```

see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html